# some questions about getcwd(), sleep() and @move_uploaded_file. working code provided

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to know three things about the following code

1. is `getcwd()` necessary
2. what is the job of `@` in front of `move_uploaded_file`
3. what's the function of `sleep(1)` in this code

---

```
$destination_path = getcwd()."uploads".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$result = 0;

$target_path = $destination_path . basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);

if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
{
   $result = 1;
}

sleep(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getcwd()`](http://php.net/getcwd) returns the current directory (from which the running PHP script was invoked). This could very well be substituted with just `"./"`

[`@()`](http://php.net/@) hides warnings in the default error handler from display. They can still be resurrected, might show up in logs, etc. Since you are probing the result anyway with the `if()` that's entirely fine.

The [`sleep()`](http://php.net/sleep) is the only mysterious part about that code. Probably depends on how the upload interacts with some AJAX script, but otherwise this is very redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with this code. The authors stated intention for the sleep command was to insure that the upload bar always displays long enough for the user to see it.

http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html